# OpenGL - Can I adjust the alpha value of an object without lighting

Tags: opengl

I am rendering a 3D object WITHOUT lighting. However, I would like to change the opacity of this object.

Is it possible? Or, will I have any rendering issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Enable blending using `glEnable(GL_BLEND)`, then choose the correct blending function you need (`glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` should be fine) and set the correct color of your model so it has an alpha component different from 1 (either from a texture or from glColor4. function).

Comment: Hello tibur,

I am sorry for the typo I put on the original post.

The correct question is updated. Basically, I would like not enable lighting but change the opacity. Is that possible?

Comment: @q0987 : tibur's answer doesn't mention lighting at all. Just enable blending, set the blending source and destination factors, and you're ready to go. Opacity is additive alpha blending.